# How to save NSTableView to text or html

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I save the contents of a NSTableView to text or html? I'd like to go through the table cell by cell and append the content to a string.

I know, many do not consider this approach in compliance with MVC, but I'm not interested in the content of the data model. The GUI display exactly the portion of data that I want and in the format I need, now I want to save exactly this representation to text or HTML.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer by telling you how to do it with a UITableView (iphone), and it should be fairly translatable:

```
NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

int numberOfCells = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];

for (int i = 0; i<numberOfCells; i++) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [myString appendString:cell.textLabel.text];
}

NSLog(@"%@", myString); // Your finished string
[myString release];
```

Comment: `for int i = 0; i < numberOfCells; i++)` is what you meant, I guess. What you have now makes no sense and should not compile.

Comment: Oh, and it should be `NSLog(@"%@\n", myString);`.

Comment: fixed, and a line break isn't at all necessary there

Comment: Ah, indeed, NSLog puts in its own linefeed. I sometimes confuse it with printf().

Comment: sorry, I couldn't get it to work with my NSTableView. I couldn't find any function responding to a NSIndexPath for NSTableView

Comment: I'm not a mac developer, but I managed to find this method: `preparedCellAtColumn:row:` - I'm sure you can use that method.